# Visual Studio complains that .exe is not found when compiling for debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a very simple C++ application.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char argv[]) {
  cout << "hi" << endl;
}
```

When I compile for the first time in debug mode, Visual Studio complains "Unable to start program ..\Debug\myprogram.exe. The system cannot find the file specified."

However, I think that this is obvious because I am compiling for the first time, right? This executable should not exist yet, so why is Visual Studio balking at compiling?

Thanks for your help.

Also, when I build, the following log appears:

When I build (Build->Build solution.), this log appears:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: print_digits, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 12/23/2011 4:32:17 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\print_digits.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\print_digits.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Debug\print_digits.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.08
```

It says build succeeded, but no executable is being built for some reason.

Comment: Can you post the full build log?

Comment: Sure (I have posted the build log above).

Comment: Can you check if the project you are trying to build is marked at: Build -> Configuration Manager ?

Comment: Hi - thanks for posting the build log: it definitely helps!  Q: As Ian Medeiros asked: please check your Config Mgr and make sure you're building the right target.  Your log doesn't say anything about trying to "compile" or "link" any ".exe".  It should...  PS: please don't mark anybody DOWN if they're trying to help you :)

Comment: I figured out that the error was that I had not added the .cpp file with the main function to my project. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of problems here:

1) This error is about trying to RUN the program, not compile it:

> "Unable to start program ..\Debug\myprogram.exe. The system cannot
>   find the file specified."

2) Probably the reason it can't find the program is because it FAILED to COMPILE.

Here are the errors I got from your source:

```
tmp.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
tmp.cpp(5) : error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'char [3]'
tmp.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
tmp.cpp(6) : warning C4508: 'main' : function should return a value; 'void' return type assumed
```

You should be able to fix these particular errors if you add "using namespace std;"

Get a clean compile, and you should be able to run the debugger :)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried Build->Clean Solution. The log notes "Build succeeded", but when I try to run the debugger, the same error appears. Indeed, after checking, no executable exists in my Debug folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Issue. The problem was that my antivirus (in my case Avast) was automatically deleting the file on creation. And because I had Avast on silent mode it did not notice me about the deletion. So disabling the antivirus or setting up a exclusion rule helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Need to write after the includes

```
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Visual Studio 2015.
If I have a solution with 2 projects and set the Output File in Linker->General to $(IntDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) then it builds an .exe file (I have verified it exists), bit I cannot run it via Visual Studio.
I currently don't have a solution to this problem, other than reverting back to $(OutDir).
The current problem is that both projects produce the object files in $(IntDir) but I get two different .exe files in the same folder.
Once I've tried to change the output location, I've been unable to get the debugger to execute the .exe file through Visual Studio, so I suspect I will need to edit the .sln or .vcxproj files to fix the problem.
Unfortunately Visual Studio is buggy and might require editing the xml files directly in these situations, if these are the problems you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because my .cpp file was not included in the project. I left-clicked and added it to the project and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when I didn't declare the libraries I was using correctly in "properties".

I think what I had to do was write the names of the .lib files in Properties/Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies and set the paths in "VC++ Directories". But you shouldn't get that problem with just stdio and iostream.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem had faced, after some RND finally i found the solution.
Solution-Go to project properties->Security Tab->Uncheck "Enable ClickOnce Security settings".